# Add a subdirectory redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to add a new path level to my search, for example:

```
wwww.website.com/s/blablabla/2
```

becomes

```
www.website.com/s/videos/blablabla/2
```

2 being the page.

However, I can't get this to work with htaccess because it keeps looping (I think that since /s/videos/ contains /s/ it keeps doing the rewrite...)

So far, I tried these codes:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/s/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /s/videos/$1 [L]
```

This give me the following error:

> The requested URL /s/videos/index.php was not found on this server.
>   Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

This code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/s/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /s/videos/$1 [L]
```

Gives me the following error:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator,
>   webmaster@website.com and inform them of the time the error
>   occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the
>   error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.

I also tried

```
RewriteRule !^s(/|$) s/videos%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

and

```
RewriteRule ^s/(.*)$ /s/videos/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

But none seems to work...

**EDIT:**

```
RewriteRule ^s/([A-Za-z0-9-\s]+)/?$ /s/videos/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Is working but only if there is no page after the search tag...

**EDIT2:**

I was able to get it working by adding multiple lines for the different scenarios:

```
RewriteRule ^s/([A-Za-z0-9-\s]+)/?$ /s/videos/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^s/([A-Za-z0-9-\s]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /s/videos/$1/$2 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Not sure if it's the proper way to do it at all though

if I do

```
RewriteRule ^s/(.*)$ /s/videos/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

It gives me

```
/s/videos/videos/videos/videos/videos/videos/videos/videos/videos/videos/videos/videos/videos/videos/videos/videos/videos/videos/videos/videos/videos/searchtag
```

**EDIT3:**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/s/(videos|members|photos)
RewriteRule ^s/(.*)$ /s/videos/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

This is working...

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^s/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /s/videos/$1/$2 [L]
```

Comment: With the page I get an internal server error, without it it does nothing (ie: /s/videos/)

Comment: Well I commented pretty much every rewrite associated with /s/ and still get the bug. I edited my post to add a line which worked, but it doesn't work if I add a page

Comment: I got it to work by adding a new rule for each scenario possible, however I really can't get it to work with a single rule that would manage all the scenarios :/

Comment: The last rule in your question,  is creating a redirect loop error, because **^s/(.*)** also matchs the target **/s/video/** and redirects **/s/video/** to itself.  Rule pattern should be diffrent if you want to avoid this error..

Comment: So I was able to get it to work by excluding the correct paths, I've edited my post to show what I have done

Comment: Yes, that is the best way to avoid redirect loop or infinite loop error on the server.

Comment: Ok so the exclusion as I did in my EDIT3 is better than having a single line for all scenarios as I did in EDIT2?